# Increments of a date using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, increment

We send mailouts every evening using SQL. For this in particular we'd like to send a reminder every 3 days, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this, or if it's even possible?

Here's my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  status = 'pending'
       AND ( date_created = sysdate - 3
              OR date_created = sysdate - 6
              OR date_created = sysdate - 9 )
```

Something to that effect, but a nicer way of coding it and also a more effective one that won't require me to go all the way into the hundreds! ^_^

Thanks

Comment: Can you ask if `sysdate - date_created` is a multiple of 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE status = 'pending'
AND MOD(sysdate-date_created, 3) = 0
```

Information on Oracle MOD: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm

Comment: if the time is insignificant you may want to use TRUNC: `MOD( (trunc(sysdate, 'DD') - trunc(date_created, 'DD')), 3 )  = 0`

Comment: This is perfect, will use it with the trunc function as mentioned above, thank you very much!